# executing bash script via CGI

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, cgi

everyone!

I have a trouble with executing .sh script from browser. 
echo command works well. But when I store the value in variable and pass it to another script as an argument it does not work.
Appreciate any help.

Example:

Here I pass $XX to another script

```
if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]; then
    exit 0
```

else

```
 XX=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_x=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
 if [ -z "$XX" ]; then
    echo "X is empty"
 else

    echo "Processing..."
    /sas/oljas_scripts/find_usage_of_tables.sh $XX
    echo "Done"
 fi

 YY=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_y=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
 ZZ=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_z=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
 echo "val_x: " $XX
 echo '<br>'
 echo "val_y: " $YY
 echo '<br>'
 echo "val_z: " $ZZ
```

fi

Comment: How specifically does it not work? What is an example of a query string that you are handling?

Comment: Hi, Amadan. The script /sas/oljas_scripts/find_usage_of_tables.sh is for parsing log and it receives "some string" as an argument and returns some result. It works through console, but not from browser.

Comment: I want result to be returned to browser

Comment: If put echo "$XX" it returns user input value to browser.

Comment: "not from browser" does not answer "how specifically does it not work". Is there an error? Did you inspect the bottom of `/var/log/apache2/error_log`? Does it output a wrong thing? What is it, if not `user_input`? Is `user_input` an exact format of the query string, or are you oversimplifying? (e.g. does it maybe have spaces?) What does it do, _exactly_?

Comment: Amadan, I do not have that directory.

edited with full code.

Comment: Wherever the error file is written. `/var/log/httpd/error_log` maybe. And you still haven't answered what exactly your input looks like (because I doubt it is `user_input`).

Comment: f.e: "cmdm.account" is my input

Comment: So if you don't have spaces, why do you need ` | sed "s/%20/ /g"`? (And if you do have spaces, you are missing some quotes: `/sas/oljas_scripts/find_usage_of_tables.sh "$XX"`). But without a description of the actual erroneous behaviour beyond "it doesn't work", I can't guess anything else.

Comment: Here is the log 

[Mon Nov 12 13:41:23 2018] [error] [client 10.1.68.243] /var/www/cgi-bin/example-bash.sh: line 48: /sas/oljas_scripts/find_usage_of_tables.sh: Permission denied, referer: http://cab-prod-comp-sd/cgi-bin/example-bash.sh?val_x=cmdm.account&val_y=&val_z=1

Comment: Check (using `ls -l`) that `/sas/oljas_scripts/find_usage_of_tables.sh` is runnable and readable for the web server user.

Comment: -rwxrw-r-- 1 sas sas   1540 Nov 12 12:58 find_usage_of_tables.sh

Comment: chmod u+x /sas/oljas_scripts/find_usage_of_tables.sh is not enough?

Comment: For you, it is. For the web server, no.

Comment: Amadan, thank you very much. changed permnission to +x. It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are trying to execute, `/sas/oljas_scripts/find_usage_of_tables.sh`, is not executable for the web server. Currently, it is:

```
-rwxrw-r-- 1 sas sas 1540 Nov 12 12:58 find_usage_of_tables.sh
```

Which means `sas` user can do everything, `sas` group can read and write but not execute, and everyone else can just read. Notably, the web server needs to be able to both read and execute the file, and it is failing to do so.

Either set the file to be readable and executable to all (not recommended):

```
chmod 755 /sas/oljas_scripts/find_usage_of_tables.sh
```

or set the group of the file to be a group the web server is in, and set the group permissions of the file accordingly:

```
chmod 754 /sas/oljas_scripts/find_usage_of_tables.sh
chgrp www-data /sas/oljas_scripts/find_usage_of_tables.sh
```

You may need `sudo` for the latter. Also, the web server's group name might not be `www-data` - inspect your web server configuration, or read it off of process list like [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41251/60565) suggests.